# "build on" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I was reading a textbook and actually I got confused about the meaning of "build on" in this sentence:

> ApplicationContexts build on the notion of a 'bean factory' by
> providing application-framework services.

actually I've searched about the meaning of 'build on', but all of them were about this to use a achievement as a base from which to achieve another thing. but in my sentence what is the another thing.

edit:
it doesn't tell us that **ApplicationContexts** are using **the notion of a 'bean factory'** to achieve what.

can you please explain the sentence and "build on" meaning to me? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think the meaning you found is wrong?

Comment: because it doesn't tell us that ***ApplicationContexts*** are using ***the notion of a 'bean factory'*** to achieve what. I can't understand the sentence's meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html), you will see that the class extends `BeanFactory`.

[*To build on something*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/build-on-sth) means to take it as a basis and develop it further.

In this case, the foundation is "the notion of a 'bean factory'" and "application-framework services" are built on top of that.

> Application Context = Bean Factory + application-framework services

Comment: Thank You SO MUCH for your detailed explanation.